# SpringLdap 2 over ldaps

Tags: ssl, spring-ldap

I've followed an interesting webinar about springLdap and I'm planning to migrate my current Ldap interface to SpringLdap. However I haven't seen any easy way to connect to an LDAPS server. In my current implementation I had to do something like:

```
String nextToken = stCc.nextToken();
Properties envP = initializeEnv(nextToken, userPassword);
    try
    {
      LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(envP, null);
      //System.out.println(nextToken + " successfully validation");
      return ctx;
    }
```

and

```
 private Properties initializeEnv(String userName, String userPassword) throws  IOException
{
 Properties envP = new Properties();
envP.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

envP.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, (String) properties.get("ldap.server.url"));
if (userName != null)
  envP.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
if (userPassword != null)
  envP.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPassword);
envP.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
envP.setProperty("java.naming.security.protocol", "ssl");
envP.setProperty("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");
envP.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "org.mycompany.ldap.CustSSLSocketFactory");
return envP;
```

}

and more:

```
public EmblSSLSocketFactory()
 {
try
{
  SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
  ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]
  {
    new DummyTrustmanager()
  }, new SecureRandom());
  socketFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ex.printStackTrace(System.err); /* handle exception */
}
```

}

Which is the equivalent (and possibly easier) way to do such authentication over TLS with SPRING-LDAP 2?

Thanks

Comment: No answer from nobody :( ?